# Lost username and password to new Mac

Tags: macos, server.app

Got Mac mini 2011 Lion Server today. Fitted extra RAM. Started up fine. Put in first bits of info. Then it does the restart and duh! Didn't write down user name and password. Did connect to internet via LAN Ethernet but cannot use wireless as needs the MAC number for to use as I setup router this way.

I am not a techie and have no idea what to do. Lion came pre-installed so no install disk and no drive anyway.

When I start up asks for username and password and of course in my haste never wrote a blasted thing down. Anyone suggest anyway out of this impasse?

Answer (score 2):

Boot the mini while holding down the Option (Alt) key. It should give you a menu where you can select the Lion Recovery partition. From there, you can reset the passwords or (if needed) reinstall the OS.

Comment: Thanks did that and managed to log in as root and update user name. Have to get to grips with this!